# Search on hashed data

Tags: hash, salt

We have a request to encrypt customer personal data (e-mail, address etc.) We use MySQL which does not have any TDE like MS SQL or Oracle. So along with encrypting data we need to preserve functionality for querying this data directly (not LIKE). So something like 
select * from person where email='blah@blah.com'.

The idea here is to use hashing and to make sure encryption is not made redundant by poor hashing function. So if we use bcrypt which has random salt built-in it should be fine.
The problem is that with random salt we can't construct the same hash again to be able to run sql queries. If I use bcrypt('blah@blah.com')  and it will return different hash value I can't run   select * from person where hash_email=bcrypt('blah@blah.com'). I can get the same hash value only if I use the same salt (and work factor). But having application-wide salt does not seem to be a great solution. So what can be done about this?

If having one salt value per application is not smart could it be a kind of improvement if we generate, say, 1000 random salt values and store them in the database?
If we need to hash email we can do the following:

1. get some fast numeric hashing function and calculate, say, m=num_hash(email) mod 1000
2. go to salt table take salt where id=m
3. hash email with this salt  email_hash=bcrypt(salt,email) and store in the database

For searching we can apply the same routine, obtain email_hash and run query. 
I guess num_hash(email) mod 1000 does not tell a great deal about the e-mail itself.
Having 1000 random salts is better than having just one.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: is not bcrypt has a built-in salt? I mean you do not generate the salt for bcrypt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts

Comment: in Java, at least, you can generate bcrypt salt and then pass it as parameter to generate hash. So if I know the salt value  I can hope to get the same hash and use it in query

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the protection provided by using a different salt for each e-mail is designed to prevent exactly the same kind of queries that you need. So, if you need efficient queries, you should either use the same salt for all e-mails, or not use salt at all.

Selecting a salt based on the hash of the e-mail is no more secure than using the same salt. To see that, you need to understand what kind of attack salts are designed to protect against. Suppose than an attacker has *n* hashes to crack, and a dictionary of *m* e-mails. If each e-mail is hashed with an individual salt, such attacker will need to hash each e-mail in the dictionary with each salt, requiring *n·m* hash calculations. However, if the same salt is used, the attacker has to hash each e-mail only once, so just *m* hash calculations are needed. If the salt is deterministically selected based on the e-mail, than again only *m* hash calculations are needed.

In general, if your applications allows fast lookups by e-mail, the attacker can run the lookup procedure on all e-mails in their dictionary. No matter how the lookup procedure is implemented, if it's fast, the attacker would be able to use it to check all their e-mails quickly. So, using salts *properly* (as they are used for password hashing) is incompatible with fast lookups.

Comment: Well, yes, I know this. The question was more about the trade-offs of any solution. We need kind of both. So something that slows down hash cracking and still gives us a way to use queries.

Comment: @MarkT74 Then use the same salt. In this case, you'll need to compute one hash per query, and an attacker will still need to hash every e-mail in their dictionary. To make hash cracking slower, increase the work factor.

Comment: Yes, I see but may be there is some way to have a cake and eat it. What if we have 1000 or 100 000 different salts.

Comment: @MarkT74 As I explained above, if the salt is selected deterministically based on e-mail, having 100000 salts is no more secure than having just one, as the attacker would still need to hash each e-mail only once. If not, you'll have to compute 100000 hashes for each query, and you can increase the work factor 100000 times instead.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Apparently my brains work as bcrypt - slow and many iterations before I get to the bottom. So I'm not much concerned about one particular email being cracked. My concern is entire database or most of it is revealed. If we have one application-wide salt then attacker can generate bcrypt hashes based on our salt and his list of e-mails.  He would just need to do this once. If we have 10 random salt values he should repeat this process 10 times. So what am I missing here that this won't slow down the attack. Again one e-mail cracked is OK but 100 000 is an issue.

Comment: @MarkT74 That's what the work factor is for. Increase it 10 times, and the attacker would need to do 10 times as much work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, encryption is not hashing and hashing is not encryption. You talk about encryption and then go on about bcrypt, but bcrypt is meant for password hashing.

Whether to use hashing or encryption depends on your needs:

- If you have data that you need not know, but that you need to check later (such as a password) must be hashed. If you only use email addresses for identification, but it is never used or displayed, then you can hash those too (though it seems weird to me). Basically data that you want nobody to know and that nobody needs to know, even if they have database access.
- If you have data that must be kept private even if someone steals a disk from the server, but you must be able to find what it read, you should use disk encryption instead of TDE (as you say, MySQL has no TDE). There is no need for TDE specifically.

Inventing your own "poor hashing function" is like trying to rewrite ssh in assembly because you didn't read its man page and failed to notice that what you want probably already exists.

Also note that bcrypt is made to be slow, literally. Querying a database that has been hashed with proper bcrypt parameters is going to be terribly inefficient. The only way to circumvent that slowness is to use bad parameters, at which point you might as well get rid of bcrypt altogether.

Comment: Yes, bcrypt is slow and we want to query by e-mail in rare cases and certainly we need e-mails in clear text. Still requirement is there. We need some way to implement this.